# Proper code style in python Flask application

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app with a single file (app.py) a large code base size of 6K lines which i want to modularize by making Separate files for each group of route handlers.

Which one is the proper approach
creating Class for similar routes like user and giving member functions like login, register
user.py

```
class User:
  def login():
    pass
  def register():
    pass
```

use it like

```
user = User()
user.login()
```

or create a python file user.py and just droping all the functions inside that

user.py

```
def login():
  pass
def register():
  pass
```

and use it like

```
import user
user.login()
```

from above mentioned approaches which one will use proper memory and more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should almost never use classes for flask routes as they are inherantly static, and so are not really suited for having instances made of them

The easiest solution is just to separate related routes into modules, as shown in the second part of your question.

If I were you I would also look into Flask's blueprints, which are specifically designed to group routes together:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/

(I would also recommend doing the tutorial for Flask that is available on the Flask website, where you make a small blogging application and blueprints and modularisation are explained http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

The latter is Pythonic.

Don't use classes when you don't need instance data; use modules.